# Android: Wrong icon on header, when app is running in backround

Tags: android, icons

On 99 % of devices app icon on header taskbar is showing without problem:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3b6A.png)

but on Sony Xperia Z3, Lollipop, it appears as white square:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TgHw.jpg)

heres application section from my manifest doc:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="intent.to.front" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="hidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".FromActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_from" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ToActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_to" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rate" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VerificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verification" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CrashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_crash" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderProgressActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order_progress"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="intent.to.front" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

So if you know answer, please help and why is it only happening to xperia device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lollipop devices add there own square to notification icons. You need to make sure that your image has an alpha background so when a color fill is applied to it, you can still see the image.

If you still want it to appear as it does on older devices you can do some checking code to see what version of Android they are running and supply a different icon.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

}
```

Comment: so, in which activity or code should that check go?

Comment: What ever code is creating that notification icon, when you set the icon to display (the white taxi on a red background), first do this check. Pass an alpha background image if the if statement breaks, if not pass your original one.

Answer (score 1):

To make Android-notification icon easily to all versions.

**[Android Assets-Notification Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html)**

Icon generators allow you to quickly and easily generate icons from existing source images, clipart, or text.

Happy Coding :)